# Appending to an array in Firebase - Asynchronous and reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I am having trouble with the asychronous nature of Firebase, particulary appending to an array from within an `observe` function.
Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated :)

The `comp` that is appended to the `users` array in the `selectUsersComp` function disappears when the firebase `observe` function is exited, even though I reload the data in the `collectionView`.

I have tried using `Dispatch.main.async` but it has not helped. I have a Firebase `observe` function inside another Firebase `observe` function. Does this change things?

```
fileprivate func fetchStartedComps() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("startedComps")
    ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate").observe(.value, with: { 
(snapshot) in
 guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }

dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
 guard let compDictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let comp = StartedComp(Id: key, dictionary: compDictionary)
            self.selectUsersComp(comp: comp)
        })
        self.filteredStartedComps = self.startedComps
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch comps for search", err)
    }
}

func selectUsersComp(comp: StartedComp) {
    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("startedComps").child(comp.title).child("invitedUsers")
     ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

  guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else { return }
        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
            if key == userId {
                    self.startedComps.append(comp)
            }
        })
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }) { (err) in
        print(err)
    }
}
```